# How to know which route is currently mapped

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "User", // Route name
                "Person/{action}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "User" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

that means if I put url like

```
http://localhost/myApp/Person/Detail
```

then it should invoke `Detail` action of `User` controller, right?

Ok, I have done it and routing also works good, means it invoke action properly.

Now if I want to get controller name then I will use

```
ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
```

and that will give me `User`, but I want it to be `Person` (i.e. as in `URL`). How can I get that?

Comment: Not tested, but does `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments` return the correct values?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Request.Url` property of `Controller` will return a [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) object containing details of the current url, including the segments.

```
string[] segments = Request.Url.Segments;
// returns ["/", "Person/", "Detail"]

string value = segments[1].Remove(segments[1].Length - 1);;
// returns "Person"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get controller name by following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

If you're in a view, then you can do:

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
```

and for custom url you can define

```
[Route("myApp/Person/{action?}")]
    public ActionResult View(string id)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return View("ViewStudent", GetStudent(id));
        }
        return View("AllStudents", GetStudents());
    }
```

Comment: OP does not want the name of the controller - they want the first segment  of the url (i.e. "Person"). And you answer is just exactly what OP already tried!